# CSRF token in GET method

Tags: java, apache, csrf, csrf-protection

I am going to avoid CSRF atack in my web application.

I've set up csrf configuration on my apache, like this:

```
<VirtualHost>
...

    CSRF_Enable on
    CSRF_Action deny
    CSRF_EnableReferer off


</VirtualHost>
```

Also, I've installed the following apache modules:

```
mod_csrf-0.3
mod_parp-0.12
mod_setenvifplus-0.23
```

that have possibility to ignore CRSF in some cases.

All stuff works fine, namely **csrfpid** add to all POST method and does not add to GET.

But one issue was found. When I try to send GET method with parameter:
**www.example.com/test.jsp?csrfpid=some_csrf_id&some_attribute=0**,
**csrfpid** token has attached to link.

I've tried to play with:

```
SetEnvIfPlus Request_Method "GET" CSRF_IGNORE=yes.
```

But, it does not work in my case.

Also, I've found, that the issue causes through **mod_csrf.c** file.

It will be good to get some ideas or helpful link regarding to the described case.

Comment: The ideal solution is to only include the CSRF token in POST requests and modify server-side actions that have state changing affect to only respond to POST requests ...  CSRF tokens in GET requests are potentially leaked at several locations: browser history, HTTP log files, network appliances that make a point to log the first line of an HTTP request, and Referer headers if the protected site links to an external site. Source: (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)